# What will be the Unit / Component / Snapshot test in Jest for Below code Sample for React Native app

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs, react-native

I am learning jest and writing component test cases for React Native App, can anyone suggest what all possible test's component test, unit, snapshot test I can write for the code below with the code snippet:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import { Colors } from '../../themes';

export default class Divider extends Component {
    render() {
        const { style } = this.props;
        return (
            <View style={[
                {
                    flex: 1,
                    height: 1,
                    backgroundColor: Colors.divider,
                    marginVertical: 8,
                }, style]} />
        );
    }
}
```

Also, suggest if the below test case I have written is good or valid:

```js
import TestRenderer from 'react-test-renderer';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import React from 'react';
import Divider from '../Divider';

test('should test on Divider props', () => {
    const testRenderer = TestRenderer.create(
        <Divider style={{ height: 10 }} />);
    const testInstance = testRenderer.root;
    const dividerView = testInstance.findByType(View).props.style[1];
    expect(dividerView.height).toBe(10);
});
```

Comment: I don't understand the reason for the downvote. Please add the comment to let me understand what is not right in the question so that I can update accordingly.

Comment: I would suggest either using `https://github.com/callstack/react-native-testing-library` or `https://github.com/testing-library/native-testing-library` for the testing. It makes it easier. Also this is a divider, which just stays on a screen. Ideally testing styles doesn't have any benefits. You can test for the props to be defined, and see if they're consumed in the expected way. The above snippet doesn't have many useful test cases in my opinion.